# How to switch seconds to a specific time zone?

Tags: javascript, timezone

I receive the variable, which is seconds. The following code I could switch seconds to date and time. The time zone is Europe where I'm now, but I have to switch it to Asian time zone. I tried add toLocaleString() behind new Date(secOfCookie * 1000), it didn't work. Could anyone give me some help? Thanks!

```
.toLocaleString("en-US", {
        timeZone: "Asia/Tokyo",
        timeZoneName: "long",
      });
```

```
function getTimeSwitchTokyoTime(secOfCookie) {
    let date = new Date(secOfCookie * 1000)
    let hours = date.getHours()
    let minutes = "0" + date.getMinutes();
    let seconds = "0" + date.getSeconds();
    let formattedTime = date + hours + ':' + minutes.substr(-2) + ':' + seconds.substr(-2);
  return formattedTime
}

getTimeSwitchTokyoTime(1665224574)
//'Sat Oct 08 2022 12:22:54 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)12:22:54'
```

Comment: Unix timestamps are *always* in terms of UTC - not any local time zone.

Answer (score 0):

I found the way, actually I thought it too complicated..
It's actually easy.

Date(millisecond) could directly switch millisecond to date, and which base on the timezone where I am.

Then I use toLocaleString() to switch to the timezone I want.

```
new Date(secOfCookie * 1000).toLocaleString(
                    "en-US",
                    {
                      timeZone: "Asia/Tokyo",
                      timeZoneName: "long",
                    })
``
```

Comment: Yes.  However, the input is not based on the time zone where you are at.  Unix timestamps are the number of second (or milliseconds) from 1 Jan 1970 at midnight UTC.  Therefore, they are *always* in terms of UTC, not any local time zone.